# Do only one move to right in 2048 game

Tags: javascript

I have 4x4 matrix like in game 2048, and I need to print result of one move to right. For example we have matrix:

```
0 0 2 2
4 4 8 4
64 64 8 4
16 8 64 8

Result is:

0 0 0 4
0 8 8 4
0 128 8 4
16 8 64 8
```

My code:

```js
function solution(x){
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
     if (x[i][j] == x[i][j+1]){
        x[i][j+1] = x[i][j+1] * 2;
        x[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(x)
}
console.log(solution([[0,0,2,2], [4,4,8,4], [64,64,8,4], [16,8,64,8]]));
console.log(solution([[2,2,4,8],[8,8,64,64],[64,8,16,8],[8,8,8,8]]))
console.log(solution([[64,64,64,64],[8,8,8,8],[4,4,4,4],[2,2,2,2]]))
console.log(solution([[0,0,4,4],[4,8,4,8],[8,8,8,8],[64,8,16,8]]))
console.log(solution([[2,0,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[8,0,0,8],[0,64,64,64]]))
```

In the second version I get wrong result on the first row [0,0,0,16], the correct result is [0, 4, 4, 8]

Comment: What should be the result for say [4,4,4,4]?

Comment: @Kaiido [0, 8, 0, 8]

Comment: then iterate right to left like @corschdi did (they even added an alignment to right, but if you remove it, then you have your expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the numbers ahead, and *then* you check the next one. So you actually create an interim result and the final outcome therefore, in a way, *is* correct:

```
[ 2, 2, 4, 8] -> [ 0, 4, 4, 8 ] -> [ 0, 0, 8, 8 ] -> [ 0, 0, 0, 16 ]
  ^  ^                ^  ^                 ^  ^                  ^
```

If you want to ignore changes made in the same run, you can increase `j` by `1` once you find a change:

#### Example that does all combinations per row, *without* taking current modifications into account

```js
function solution(x) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
      if (x[i][j] == x[i][j + 1] && x[i][j] !== 0) {
        x[i][j + 1] = x[i][j] * 2;
        x[i][j] = 0;
        j += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(x)
}

console.log(solution([[0,0,2,2], [4,4,8,4], [64,64,8,4], [16,8,64,8]]));
console.log(solution([[2,2,4,8],[8,8,64,64],[64,8,16,8],[8,8,8,8]]))
console.log(solution([[64,64,64,64],[8,8,8,8],[4,4,4,4],[2,2,2,2]]))
console.log(solution([[0,0,4,4],[4,8,4,8],[8,8,8,8],[64,8,16,8]]))
console.log(solution([[2,0,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[8,0,0,8],[0,64,64,64]]))
```

If you just want 1 change per row, you can use `break`

#### Example with `break`, only does *1* update per row

```js
function solution(x) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
      if (x[i][j] == x[i][j + 1] && x[i][j] !== 0) {
        x[i][j + 1] = x[i][j] * 2;
        x[i][j] = 0;
        // If you only want one move, you can break here
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(x)
}

console.log(solution([[0,0,2,2], [4,4,8,4], [64,64,8,4], [16,8,64,8]]));
console.log(solution([[2,2,4,8],[8,8,64,64],[64,8,16,8],[8,8,8,8]]))
console.log(solution([[64,64,64,64],[8,8,8,8],[4,4,4,4],[2,2,2,2]]))
console.log(solution([[0,0,4,4],[4,8,4,8],[8,8,8,8],[64,8,16,8]]))
console.log(solution([[2,0,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[8,0,0,8],[0,64,64,64]]))
```

Comment: They actually want to modify in place... [4,4,4,4] should be [0,8,0,8] (or [0,0,8,8] if aligned)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up. Didn't see that added requirement. I'll make a quick update to my answer.

Comment: @user3297291 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the numbers to the right, you'll need to traverse the array from right to left. Also, in 2048 you'll need to move all numbers to the right after each merge.

This will work:

```js
function solution(x) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (let j = x.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (x[i][j - 1] == x[i][j]) {
        x[i][j] = x[i][j] * 2;

        // move all numbers on the left to the right by one
        if (j > 1) {
          for (let k = j - 1; k > 0; k--) {
            x[i][k] = x[i][k - 1];
          }
        }
        x[i][0] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(x)
}
console.log(solution([
  [0, 0, 2, 2],
  [4, 4, 8, 4],
  [64, 64, 8, 4],
  [16, 8, 64, 8]
]));
console.log(solution([
  [2, 2, 4, 8],
  [8, 8, 64, 64],
  [64, 8, 16, 8],
  [8, 8, 8, 8]
]))
console.log(solution([
  [64, 64, 64, 64],
  [8, 8, 8, 8],
  [4, 4, 4, 4],
  [2, 2, 2, 2]
]))
console.log(solution([
  [0, 0, 4, 4],
  [4, 8, 4, 8],
  [8, 8, 8, 8],
  [64, 8, 16, 8]
]))
console.log(solution([
  [2, 0, 4, 4],
  [4, 4, 4, 4],
  [8, 0, 0, 8],
  [0, 64, 64, 64]
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, verbose solution. (I'm sure a much more elegant one is possible):

```js
function newState(oldState){
  // Defines an array to hold our result
  let result = [];
  // Examines each row of the old state separately
  for (let row of oldState){
    // Names the columns a, b, c, & d
    let a = row[0], b = row[1], c = row[2], d = row[3];
    // Checks for match in the rightmost pair
    if(d == c && d != 0){
      d = d * 2; // Combines matching cells
      // Checks for secondary match
      if(b == a && b != 0){
        // Traditional 2048 logic: combines matching cells *into 'c'* & shifts the rest
        c = b * 2; b = 0; a = 0;
        // For the alternative logic requested in a comment by OP,
        //   replace the above line with `c = 0; b = b * 2; a = 0;`
      }
      else{
        c = b; b = a; a = 0; // Shifts the rest
      }
    }
    else{
      // Checks for match in the middle pair
      if(c == b && c != 0){
        c = c * 2; b = a; a = 0; // Combines matching cells and shifts the rest
      }
      else{
        // Checks for match in the leftmost pair
        if(b == a && b != 0){
          b = b * 2; a = 0; // Combines matching cells and shifts the rest
        }
      }
    }
    // Populates the current row in the result matrix
    result.push([a, b, c, d]);
  }
  // Returns the result matrix
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}
  
console.log(newState([[0,0,2,2], [4,4,8,4], [64,64,8,4], [16,8,64,8]]));
console.log(newState([[2,2,4,8],[8,8,64,64],[64,8,16,8],[8,8,8,8]]));
console.log(newState([[64,64,64,64],[8,8,8,8],[4,4,4,4],[2,2,2,2]]));
console.log(newState([[0,0,4,4],[4,8,4,8],[8,8,8,8],[64,8,16,8]]));
console.log(newState([[2,0,4,4],[4,4,4,4],[8,0,0,8],[0,64,64,64]]));
```